# Kotlin Run/Debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Have created simple Kotlin project in IDEA, with only `Main.kt` file

[image]

When I have pressed K in margin to left of 'main', Run/Debug congiguration automatically was created

[image]

But when I run this configuration, I got error:

[image]

Invalidate IDEA cache and restart does not help.

Please suggest how can I run `Main.kt`?

Comment: configuration & setup looks good, what version of intellij are you using? is it the latest?

Comment: also, try adding `apply plugin: 'application'` and `mainClassName = 'MainKt'` to your gradle configuration and see if you can run it with `./gradlew run` (or `gradlew.bat run` on windows)

Comment: IDEA 2017.3
If I execute build and run tasks from Gradle pane, they are succeed. The problem occurs if I try to compile or run using buttons in toolbar. Your suggestion, unfortunately, doesn't help.

Comment: Hm I'm also using idea 2017.3 with no problems, maybe your gradle version is too old? Latest version 4.4 works for me

Comment: Tried 4.0 and 4.4, doesn't matter. Created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184404

Answer (score 0):

*This answer relates to an earlier version of the question, which was about confusion between scripting and compiled Kotlin.*

## The problem

You are trying to run a Kotlin file designed for compiled mode in scripting mode.

## General Info

### Script mode

Scripts look like this:

```
val a = 8
println(a)
```

They also usually have the extension `.kts`, which is why you had issues with the file picker.

### Compiled mode

Whereas what you wrote looks like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = 8
    println(8)
}
```

These files normally have the extension `.kt`

## Solution

You need to decide which mode you want to use, and use the appropriate file name and format for the file.

Comment: I need compiled mode. In fact I have 'Test.kt' file with 'main' function only inside, and want to run it. But if I choice 'Kotlin' configuration, what 'Main class' should I point to?

Comment: The main kotlin file (I think you called it `Desktoplauncher.kt`), although you should see a K in the margin by the main method that will create the profile automatically

Comment: You right, file name is DesktopLauncher.kt. Thank you for tip about K in the margin, didn't knew that!
The profile is created with DesktopLauncherKt as main class, but running it still error:
Error: Could not find or load main class DesktopLauncherKt

Comment: Was that with the K or not? The K should work and set all the parameters automatically

Comment: Now got another problem :( Have updated my post to clarify the problem.

Comment: Have you changed anything about your project from the default settings?

Comment: No, didn't touch anything.